# Laravel 4 blade include non-blade file

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is it possible to use `@include()` to include non-blade file? I tried with this `@include('cms/include.json.php')` and it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Should be working, since `@include` is simply transpiled to `<?php echo $__env->make(...)->render(); ?>`. It'd have to be under `views` folder though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, Laravel just parses it into normal php code, so in this case on a non blad file just using `<?php include("filepath"); ?>` should work!

Just because laravel uses blade doesn't mean you can't use php like normal still.

Comment: where is the path to file.php for include("file.php")?

Comment: @cawecoy You can use Laravel's [helper functions](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths) here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it *doesn't work* due to the fact any errors which might be thrown from this line of code is being suppressed by the `@` syntax.. To see what exactly is going on, you should remove the error suppression & enable `E_ALL` on the error reporting.

It's most likley due to an incorrectly specified directory

Comment: Actually, they're not suppressed. The `@include` command is parsed by the framework itself before being sent to the PHP interpreter.

Comment: @Raphael_ Oh, That I did not know. Thanks for the info!